# pass variable with jquery to Php for MySQL deletion

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to delete a row from my database by clicking an icon. To put it simply it is not working and I cannot figure out why. Read over many of the related questions on here as well as some tutorials around the web. Still new to php and ajax so excuse the noob mistakes if any. Thanks in adavance Cheers.

### Jquery

```
$('.delete').click(function(){

  // get resource id to use for deleting

  var del_id = $(this).attr('data-resource-id');

  // get parent 
  var parent = $(this).parent().parent();

  var transitionEnd = 'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend';
  
  $.post('includes/delete-resource.php', {id:del_id},function(data){

      // animation out 
      parent.addClass('remove-resource').one(transitionEnd, function(){

      parent.remove();

    }); // end addClass
  }); // end post
}); // end function
```

### PHP - delete-resource.php

```
require_once('config.php');

//connect to $db
require_once('database.php');

// Fetch posted id sent from click
$resource_id = $_POST['id'];
$safe_id = filter_var($resource_id,FILTER_SANITIZE_INT);

  try {
      // prepare Statement
    $remove = $db->prepare(
      "DELETE FROM resources
       WHERE resource_id = :safe_id");
        // Bind 
    $remove->bindParam(':safe_id', $safe_id);
        // run query
    $remove->execute();
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be removed";
    exit;
  }

  if($remove -> rowCount()){
    echo 'success';
  } else {
    echo 'fail';
  }
```

Comment: is `$resource_id` posted to delete-resource.php?

Comment: I dont know how to find out? is there an easy way? I am just assuming the ajax post is running because on click my animation runs which is inside the ajax function.

Comment: firebug for firefox or the equivalent for other browsers

Comment: So I changed the href of my button to follow the link to delete-resource.php and did a var dump of $resource_id it is returning NULL

Answer (score 0):

If the `.delete` element are an hyperlink you may want to stop it's default behavior with the help of `event.preventDefault()`

```
$('.delete').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // get resource id to use for deleting

  // ...
```

Comment: the original .delete element href was javascript:void(0) I dont think I would have to prevent default on this? I changed href to delete-resource.php to be able to follow it and do a var_dump and see what it was dumping to the screen. Would changing the link to a real href effect the ajax function?

Comment: I think changing the link to the real href will make it go to that location right after your $post has been called, but as a new instance.  Resulting in that you will never see the result of your $post call.

Comment: What you could do is change it back to javascript:void(0) and then  debug the `data` that you get back inside your $post callback.

Comment: if you put `console.log(data);` inside your $post callback and then open the console in chrome developer-tools (ctrl+shift+I).. what you get?

Comment: Thanks Jimbo did what you suggest and was able to debug it was a damn syntax error...

CHEERS!